# trying to INSERT NULL if input field left blank

Tags: php, mysql, insert, null

I'm trying to insert NULL into the mySQL databse with PHP.

I've got:

```
$myVariable=$_POST[inputfield];        
if(!is_numeric($myVariable) || $myVariable==0){

$myVariable=NULL;
}
```

My database field is decimal, and IS NULL has been set. It keeps reverting to 0.00 if input is left blank. How do I set NULL if left blank, so I can call a php if NULL function?

**Edit** Calling if NULL in decimal is not correct?

```
<? if ($debit==NULL || $debit=="0.00") {echo 'Awaiting Cost';} 
elseif ($debit != NULL || $debit!="0.00") { echo "£$debit";}?>
```

This displays my message correctly, so if if NULL is useless for a decimal i'll just leave 0.00. Is this hacky?

SQL structure for those who asked:

```
 `myTableField` decimal(10,2) default NULL,
```

Comment: The problem is with your sql or with your data model. Show the rest of your code.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't also set a default? If you did this in phpmyadmin, although the field might be NULL you also need to set default to NULL otherwise it seems to go to 0

Comment: Added the SQL. I've set default to NULL, so it must be a decimal field issue?

Comment: `$_POST[inputfield]` will issue a notice. Avoid using that and always explicitly use an integer or a string when looking for an array element (`$_POST['inputfield']`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are composing an SQL statement by appending the value of the `$myVariable` variable, then you should look if it's `NULL` or not and modify the SQL statement accordingly.

For example, if your code is something like:

```
$sql .= "myVariable = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($myVariable) . "'";
```

then you should change it to something like:

```
if (is_null($myVariable)) {
    $sql .= "myVariable = NULL";
} else {
    $sql .= "myVariable = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($myVariable) . "'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it on the SQL side:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (`field1`) VALUES (IF($myVariable == 0, NULL, $myVariable))";
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$myVariable="NULL";
```

.
if your code is:

```
$val=NULL;
mysql_query("SET @v=$val");
```

the MySQL got the string:

```
SET @v=0;
```

it's like using :

```
echo "SET @v=$val";
```

Answer (score -1):

you can filter field's data in MySQL itself, using a TRIGGER:

```
CREATE TRIGGER table1_update BEFORE UPDATE ON table1 FOR EACH ROW SET
    NEW.num=IF(NEW.num=0 ,NULL,NEW.num),
    NEW.txt=IF(NEW.txt="",NULL,NEW.txt);
CREATE TRIGGER table1_create BEFORE INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW SET
    NEW.num=IF(NEW.num=0 ,NULL,NEW.num),
    NEW.txt=IF(NEW.txt="",NULL,NEW.txt);
```